# Natural deduction and introduction of universal quantifier

Tags: logic, solution-verification, quantifiers, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have a hard time with quantification introduction and elimination ; for instance, if I want to prove
$$\forall x \quad (Px\rightarrow Px ) $$

I am tempted to do the following :
$$\underline{[Py]}_{\, I\rightarrow} \\\underline{\quad \ Py \rightarrow Py \quad}_{\,I \, \forall}
\\\forall x \  (Px\rightarrow Px )
 $$

But I am not convinced since $y$ is not non-free in $Py \rightarrow Py$ (or is it?)

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivation is perfectly valid. Indeed, in [natural deduction](https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/natural_deduction_for_first_order_logic.html), the rule
$$
\frac{A(y)}{\forall x \, A(x)}\forall_\text{intro}
$$
can be applied only when the variable $y$ does not occur free in the *undischarged* hypotheses of the derivation.
The undischarged hypotheses of  derivation are the *leaves* of the derivation trees (i.e. the formula occurrences that do not have any premise above them) that have not been discharged yet.

Now, your derivation before applying the rule $\forall_\text{intro}$ is
$$
\frac{[Py]^*}{Py \to Py}\to_\text{intro}^*
$$
where there are *not* undischarged hypotheses, because the hypothesis $Py$ has been discharged by the rule $\to_\text{intro}$ (the symbol ${}^*$ marks when the hypotheses has been discharged). Therefore, when you apply the rule $\forall_\text{intro}$, the condition "$y$ does occur free in the undischarged hypotheses of the derivation" is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), since there are no undischarged hypotheses in that moment.

Clearly, $y$ occurs free in $Py \to Py$. However, note that when you apply the rule $\forall_\text{intro}$, the formula occurrence  $Py \to Py$ is *not* an hypothesis in your derivation, because it has a premise above it, $[Py]$.